# Woocommerce discount: add negative fees without taxes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, fee

I am adding a WooCommerce cart fee like so :

```
  add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function($cart) { 
      $cart->add_fee(__('Popust za vjernost'), -10, 0);
  });
```

I thought adding a 0 as the third argument would set the tax to 0 but WooCommerce still adds tax to the fee.

How can I set the tax to 0?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ah, I see, and there is no way to override the taxes?  Have you any suggestions for other options?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec In the answer you reference as a duplicate, you do not solve the issue of adding a discount without tax.  Do you not think other people might want a solution to this problem?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec OK, would I do that by accessing the fee object directly, or subtracting the tax from the cart total?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I think it's worth posting the solution as an answer, I can see other people finding it useful.

Comment: I've posted a feature request to add a `add_discount` method to the cart.

Comment: Well I fixed it by editing WooCommerce's core changing `class-wc-cart-totals.php` lines `330` `$fee->object->tax_data = wc_remove_number_precision_deep(0);` and ``331`  `$fee->object->tax      = wc_remove_number_precision_deep(0);` not ideal but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting cores files is not a solution, as it can affect other processes and you will lose your changes each time you will update WooCommerce.

Using `WC_Cart` `add_fee()` method **with a negative amount, is a tweak to add a discount**. In that case, **the "taxable" optional 3rd argument doesn't work, and taxes are always applied**. This has been reported to WooCommerce many times and the response was that `WC_Cart` `add_fee()` method was not made for discounts.

##### 1) Reminder about [`WC_Cart` `add_fee()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1906-L1943) 4 available arguments:

```php
/**
 * Add additional fee to the cart.
 *
 * This method should be called on a callback attached to the
 * woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees action during cart/checkout. Fees do not
 * persist.
 *
 * @uses WC_Cart_Fees::add_fee
 * @param string $name      Unique name for the fee. Multiple fees of the same name cannot be added.
 * @param float  $amount    Fee amount (do not enter negative amounts).
 * @param bool   $taxable   Is the fee taxable? (default: false).
 * @param string $tax_class The tax class for the fee if taxable. A blank string is standard tax class. (default: '').
 */
WC()->cart->add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable, $tax_class );
```

##### 2) Make the "taxable" 3rd argument working with negative amounts:

The following code will enable "taxable" when using a negative amount, **allowing to add a discount without taxes** when the **"taxable" argument is set to `false`**:

```php
// Adjust cart total amount
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_get_total', 'filter_cart_get_total', 10, 1 );
function filter_cart_get_total( $total ) {
    $tax_amount = 0;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) {
        if( ! $fee->taxable && $fee->tax < 0 ) {
            $tax_amount -= $fee->tax;
        }
    }

    if( $tax_amount != 0 ) {
        $total += $tax_amount;
    }
    return $total;
}

// Adjust Fee taxes (array of tax totals)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_get_fee_taxes', 'filter_cart_get_fee_taxes', 10, 1 );
function filter_cart_get_fee_taxes( $fee_taxes ) {
    $fee_taxes = array();
    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) {
        if( $fee->taxable ) {
            foreach( $fee->tax_data as $tax_key => $tax_amount ) {
                if( isset($fee_taxes[$tax_key]) ) {
                    $fee_taxes[$tax_key] += $tax_amount;
                } else {
                    $fee_taxes[$tax_key] = $tax_amount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $fee_taxes;
}

// Displayed fees: Remove taxes from non taxable fees with negative amount
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_fee_html', 'filter_cart_totals_fee_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee_html, $fee ) {
    if( ! $fee->taxable && $fee->tax < 0 ) {
        return wc_price( $fee->total );
    }
    return $fee_html;
}

// Adjust Order fee item(s) for negative non taxable fees
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_fee_item', 'alter_checkout_create_order_fee_item', 10, 4 );
function alter_checkout_create_order_fee_item( $item, $fee_key, $fee, $order ) {
    if ( ! $fee->taxable && $fee->tax < 0 ) {
        $item->set_taxes(['total' => []]);
        $item->set_total_tax(0);
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

---

##### 3) Testing using `Add_fee()`:

Below, we add a discount without taxes using a negative amount:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_discount_without_tax' );
function add_discount_without_tax( $cart ) { 
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    // Add a NON taxable DISCOUNT (negative amount, "taxable" argument set to "false")
    $cart->add_fee(__('Discount (no tax)'), -10, false); 
};
```

This time it works, taxes are not applied and when order is submitted, same thing.

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Comment: Thanks Loic, I did think of this method but the tax still appears in the order fee in the order.  My client did not want this so I had to edit the core files.  I did try returning 0 in this filter `woocommerce_cart_totals_get_fees_from_cart_taxes` but it did not work, any ideas why?

Comment: Hold on, I didn't see the `filter_cart_get_fee_taxes`  function, I though you were just adding the taxes back to the cart totals.  I will test it now.

Comment: I've tested and the taxes do not appear in order.  Cheers Loic you are the master!

Answer (score 0):

To set the tax to 0 for a WooCommerce cart fee, you can use the fourth argument of the `add_fee` method to specify that tax should not be applied. Here's how you can modify your code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function($cart) { 
    $cart->add_fee(__('Popust za vjernost'), -10, false, '');
});
```

By passing `false` as the third argument and an empty string `''` as the fourth argument, you are indicating that no tax should be applied to the fee. This should prevent WooCommerce from adding tax to the fee.

Comment: No,  I have updated the code and it is still adding the tax in the order.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest shorter and more understandable solution than provided by LoicTheAztec. Thanks to him for the inspiration. You can modify fee tax by changing value in `'total' => array()`

```
private function cart_apply_negative_fee( $fee_name, $amount ) {
    add_action(
        'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees',
        function ( $cart ) use ( $fee_name, $amount ) {
            $cart->add_fee( $fee_name, $amount * -1 );
        }
    );
    $this->cart_override_fee_tax_to_zero( $fee_name );
    $this->order_override_fee_tax_to_zero( $fee_name );
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
}

private function cart_override_fee_tax_to_zero( $fee_name ) {
    add_filter(
        'woocommerce_cart_totals_get_fees_from_cart_taxes',
        function ( $fee_taxes, $fee, $cart ) use ( $fee_name ) {
            if ( $fee->object->name !== $fee_name ) {
                return $fee_taxes;
            }
            return array( 'total' => 0 );
        },
        10,
        3
    );
}

private function order_override_fee_tax_to_zero( $fee_name ) {
    add_action(
        'woocommerce_order_item_fee_after_calculate_taxes',
        function ( $order_item_fee, $calculate_tax_for ) use ( $fee_name ) {
            if ( $order_item_fee->get_name() !== $fee_name ) {
                return;
            }
            $order_item_fee->set_taxes( array( 'total' => array() ) );
        },
        10,
        2
    );
}
```